# Как работает восстановление пароля?

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет! 
Не могу понять, как работает компонент восстановления пароля (bitrix:system.auth.forgotpasswd). 
Подключаю его очень просто:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:system.auth.forgotpasswd",
".default",
Array()
);
```

Выводится форма с двумя полями - логин и почта. Логин я удалил из шаблона, оставил только почту. 
Жму кнопку отправить, форма просто перезагружается, и всё. Никаких сообщений, что письмо отправлено или что почта, например, указана неверно. 
Форму я открываю по урлу

```
/auth/?forgot_password=yes&back_url=%2Fpersonal%2Forder%2F
```

И этот же урл прописывается в action самой формы

```
<form name="bform" method="post" target="_top" action="<?=$arResult["AUTH_URL"]?>">
```

Т.е. здесь $arResult["AUTH_URL"] - это как раз /auth/?forgot_password=yes&back_url=%2Fpersonal%2Forder%2F. 
Ну, собственно, поэтому форма и перезагружается, что а action стоит адрес страницы с этой формой, а на самой странице нет ничего, кроме:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:system.auth.forgotpasswd",
".default",
Array()
);
```

Ещё непонятно назначение параметра

```
back_url=%2Fpersonal%2Forder%2F
```

Answer (score 1):

Компонент "bitrix:system.auth.forgotpasswd" нет необходимости размещать самостоятельно, достаточно создать, например, страницу /auth/index.php (при установке демо-сайта обычно она создается автоматически) с примерно следующим содержимым:

```
<?
define("NEED_AUTH", true);
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST["backurl"]) && strlen($_REQUEST["backurl"])>0) 
    LocalRedirect($backurl);

$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Авторизация");
?>
<p>Вы зарегистрированы и успешно авторизовались.</p>

<p><a href="<?=SITE_DIR?>">Вернуться на главную страницу</a></p>

<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Назначение параметра backurl - возвращать на указанную в данном параметре страницу после успешной авторизации.

Comment: Понятно, но что делать, если мне нужно, чтобы на форме авторизации была ссылка "Забыли пароль?", по которой аяксом в контейнере с формой авторизации должна появляется форма восстановления пароля?

Comment: Можете использовать те же стандартные урлы для вывода аякс формы, и их же для отправки запроса. Шаблон компонента можно скопировать в шаблон сайта под именем .default, и тогда он будет использоваться по умолчанию. Чтобы обрезать все до и после шаблона, используйте $APPLICATION->RestartBuffer(); и die();.

Answer (score 1):

Долго объяснять, попробуйте так:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:system.auth.forgotpasswd",
    ".default",
    Array("AUTH_RESULT" => $APPLICATION->arAuthResult)
);
```